# Aligning text over a div element

Tags: css, html

I want the 2012 to be to the left of the first map (almost where it is), and the 2010 to be to the left of the second map. I can't post the screenshot, as I am a new user, but they are to the left and to the right of the page.

This is my code:

```
<b>2012<b>
<div id="map_canvas2" style="width:25%; height:25%"></div>
<b>2010<b>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:25%; height:25%"></div>
```

After searching I see that you have to do it with CSS, but how? I feel that if I set something in CSS to be to the left, all text goes to the left.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you are not closing your `b` tag

Answer (score 0):

Put this in the css code.

```
<style type="text/css">
   b,div{float:left;}
   .cls{clear:both;}
</style>
```

HTML code:

```
<b>2012</b>
<div id="map_canvas2" style="width:25%; height:25%">div 1</div>
    <br class="cls"/>
<b>2010</b>
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:25%; height:25%"> div 2</div>    <br class="cls"/>
​
```

this ought to do it.

Comment: I have a separate css file, but the text just was misplaced under eachother, and the right map became lower than the left..

Answer (score 0):

I think you should code like this:-

**HTML**

```
<div id="map_canvas"><b>2012<b></div>
<div id="map_canvas2"><b>2010<b></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#map_canvas {
float:left;
background:red;
width:300px;
height:200px;
}

#map_canvas2 {
float:right;
background:green;
width:300px;
height:200px;
}
```

see the demo :- http://jsfiddle.net/3XBNa/1/